# Are there any linkage functions that can handle signed dissimilarity matrix?

Tags: clustering, matrix, distance

I know that a "distance" matrix is a symmetric positive matrix where the diagonal is zero.  A "dissimilarity" matrix, to my understanding, is a generalization of a distance matrix.  In my situation, I have a "dissimilarity" matrix that is symmetric and the diagonal is zero BUT the values are both negative and positive.  I guess this is called a signed dissimilarity matrix.  I'd like to use hierarchical clustering for this but, of course, linkage functions cannot handle this data structure.

**Is anyone aware of unsupervised clustering methods or linkage functions for hierarchical clustering that can handle a positive/negative domain for a dissimilarity matrix?**

I couldn't find many references to this type of data structure as I know it's non-conventional.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14961747/signed-distance-matrix-in-r

The only way I could think of handling this would be to calculate the Euclidean distance of my dissimilarity matrix.  Would that be valid? Is that my only option at the moment?

Comment: What do these negative values mean in view that the matrix is a dissimilarity one, with zero diagonal. d(i ,i)=0 is the identity of an object with itself. Then what does d(i,j)<0 may mean?

Comment: Thanks for asking.  I should have made this more clear in the actual question.  I have correlation matrix A and B which both have the same covariates/features.  The dissimilarity is B - A so if the values are positive they are greater in B and if they are negative they are greater in A.  The "dissimilarity" in this case is signed as its the distance between the 2 correlation values.   I could use the absolute value but the clusters turn out to be heterogenous in terms of features that are higher in A or higher in B.  Let me know if this makes sense. @ttnphns

Comment: I'm wondering if there is anything like spring_layout where there are forces that "push" and "pull" based on sign. @ttnphns

Comment: But the "distance" between two correlation values (ij) is the change in correlation, it cannot be understood as a (dis)similarity between items i and j. Your matrix isn't a dissimilarity matrix, it is just a matrix of numbers.

Comment: I understand but I'm trying to extend the concept of a distance matrix to a signed form as there is directionality in this case.  Each i,j in the matrix represents a distance between 2 correlation matrices and the diagonal is 0.  The value of 3 is the same units and magnitude as a value of -3 but they are interpreted differently.

Comment: So, it appears that your similarity matrix is a matrix of _residual correlations_, right? For example, matrix 1 could be observed correlations and matrix 2 could be predicted or restored correlations.

Comment: A would be correlations from condition 1 while B would be correlations form condition 2 but your example works as well.

Comment: If that is your case then just keep 1s on the diagonal of that residual correlation matrix. In other words, take the difference only between the off-diagonal portions of the matrices. Keeping 1 diagonal leaves your matrix a similarity (not dissimilarity) matrix, which correlation matrix - be it original or residual - is.

Comment: You yay also set 2 rather 1 on the diagonal, because the maximal possible off-diagonal value, the difference of correlations can be 2